# LibreOffice Writer - equivalent to Word's "No Markup" option?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Colleagues and I are editing documents in Word using the "Track changes" feature, then sending these to a colleague who has only LibreOffice Writer.

He said he is finding the many suggestions confusing, so I suspect he may be seeing the document using the Writer equivalent of Word's "All Markup" view option, where each change is individually highlighted.

Is there an equivalent to Word's "No Markup" view option, where just the final result of the changes is displayed, without identifying individual changes?

Here is how Microsoft describe [these options](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/track-changes-in-word-197ba630-0f5f-4a8e-9a77-3712475e806a):

- For a detailed view of the changes, choose **All Markup**.
- For a preview of how the document will look if you make all the suggested changes permanent, choose **No Markup**.

Though I have searched for help on the equivalent features in Writer, I can find no mention of this. The closest I found is an article [How to use the LibreOffice Track Changes toolbar](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-the-libreoffice-track-changes-toolbar/), but even this lacks the information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable "Show Track changes" by either:

1. Going to Edit menu -> Track Changes -> click on `Show` or
2. Using the Track Changes toolbar, clicking the first icon on the left.

[image: IMG:]